# Electric fireplace in AFCI circuit

Tags: afci

I have a new 15amp circuit with AFCI breakers. It is dedicated for 120v electric fireplace. The issue I am facing is that the moment I turn the fireplace on the breaker trips. My questions are -

1. Shall I replace AFCI with a regular 15amp breaker?
2. Shall I replace the regular receptacle with an AFCI receptacle and afci breaker with regular breaker and still maintain the security of orginal AFCI breaker?

Thanks, looking forward to all the suggestions.

Comment: AFCI looks for sparks/arcs in the wiring.  Should not have any with electric fireplace, maybe a gas one with an igniter.  I would check the fireplace and the wiring first, then maybe think of changing with the breaker/outlets.

Comment: When a breaker trips (any type of breaker, for any reason) your first thought should be "there's a wiring problem", not "my breaker is bad". Did you have a licensed electrician install the circuit? If so, call her back and ask her to trouble shoot. Also, do the fireplace instructions say it's compatible with AFCI protection?

Comment: The AFCI might be a red herring.  A breaker tripping as soon as a switch is turned on, usually is a short on the switch hot wire, usually in the switch box.  A screw or ground wire too close.